# Not getting the selected drop down list item back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get a selected item from a dropdown list in the model. But I am always getting null vale for the item.
My model is

```
public class Configuration
{
    public Color BoderColor { get; set; }
}

public class Color
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I am binding dropdown list like this

```
<td>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BoderColor, new SelectList(ViewBag.Colors,  "Id","Name" ))
</td>
```

ViewBag.Colors is of type `IEnumerable<Color>`

And this is my action method.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Configuration configItem)
    {
        try
        {
            var color = configItem.BoderColor;
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

When I submit my view, I am expecting the selected color should be able to access via 'BoderColor' in model object. Can somebody help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: can you show the action method?

Comment: Added my action method. Though I have removed actual call to the BL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an int property in your model representing the selected id for the color :

```
public class Configuration
{
    public Color BoderColor { get; set; }
    public int BoderColorId { get; set; }
}
```

And then use it in the helper

```
<td>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BoderColorId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Colors,  "Id","Name" ))
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am able to access the Id. But I am trying to access the selected Color item instead of selected color id.

Comment: The property you have to select is a simple type, it is the value returned by the dropdown list. In this case the value will be "Id" and assuming it is an int, you can map it to BoderColorId, not to BoderColor.

Comment: So can't we able to select the Color instead of color id?

Comment: As already said: No. The dropdownlist returns the Id value of the selectlist, that is an integer and not a Color type.